# How can I write += operation with mutables in F#

Tags: f#

with the simple case of, in C#:

```
i += 1;
```

how can I write this with a mutable in F#, other than:

```
i <- i + 1
```

is there a shorter syntax?

Comment: I don't really think saving two characters really justifies a special syntactic construct. Incrementing counters is also not something you usually do a whole lot in functional languages. Instead you'd use higher level constructs like `List.map`, or `List.mapi` if you actually need the index too.

Comment: You could improve your question by providing some reason as to *why* you want to increment a mutable. One reason F# doesn't have increment operators is that the use of such would be a terrible code smell in FP.

Comment: I was trying to walk through 2 lists at the same time and count some events; I realize now that there are different ways to do it, but it's like F# day 5 or 6 :)

Comment: @Thomas Been there, Done that. Takes some time to rewire the brain into functional. But after a while you’ll cringe at the sight of “mutable” ;)

Comment: Yes, I can imagine because I see quite elegant solutions to problems; I need to get used to breaking down problems in the proper way now, which is quite a bit of mental gymnastics :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, F# and Functional Programming in general discourage mutability. Thus the language doesn't make writing mutable code convenient.

If you love `+=` you can create that operator by yourself:

```
let inline (+=) a b = a := !a + b
// test
let a = ref 100
a += 2
printfn "%d" !a // 102
```

You can check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/reference-cells) for more information about the `Ref` type.

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK there's no built-in operator for increment mutables in place but there's a built-in function to increment `int ref` values.

```
let x = ref 0
incr x
printfn "%A" !x  // ! dereferences an int ref
```